# Is there a way to set a number to equal a date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a few files that have a randomly generated number that corresponds with a date:

```
736815 = 01/05/2018
```

I need to create a function or process that applies logic to sequential numbers so that the next number equals the next calendar date.

Ideally i would need it in a key:pair format, so that when i convert the file to a new format i can apply the date in place of the auto file name.

Hopefully this makes more sense, it is to be used to name a converted file.

Comment: why the pandas tag? if you are dealing with a dataframe provide that context

Comment: These tags where already there... can you suggest better ones?

Comment: Well, are you interested in using pandas or not. That makes a rather big difference for the possible solutions.

Comment: i'm interested in using whatever does the job @deceze. I was under the impression pandas was the wrong tag to use

Comment: what are the down votes for? it's pretty much a well structured question.....

Comment: @JK1993 it is not, to be honest. How "random" should that number be? what date would you like to start from? how many pairs do you even want? in what format should the output be (dict, tuples)?

Comment: ahhh, well said @DeepSpace one sec.. let me rewrite it

Comment: hopefully that makes more sense @DeepSpace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `origin` parameter is possible use here, also add `unit='D'` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[5678, 5679, 5680]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'] - 5678, unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'))
print (df)
    col       date
0  5678 2020-01-01
1  5679 2020-01-02
2  5680 2020-01-03
```

Non pandas solution, only pure python with same idea:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
L = [5678, 5679, 5680]

a = [timedelta(x-5678) + datetime(2020,1,1)  for x in L]
print (a)
[datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: I don't think OP is actually using pandas. They said the tags were suggested by SO

Comment: if pandas is needed i can just import it]

Comment: @JK1993 using pandas for this only is a huge overkill. It can be solved in two lines of ""pure"" python code

Comment: @DeepSpace what are the two lines please?

Answer (score 2):

The number doesn't need to translate into the date directly in any way. You just need to pick a start date and a number, and add another number either via simple addition or via a `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from random import randint

start_date = date.today()
start_int = randint(1000, 10000)

for i in range(10):
    print(start_int + i, start_date + timedelta(days=i))
```

```
6964 2020-01-29
6965 2020-01-30
6966 2020-01-31
6967 2020-02-01
6968 2020-02-02
6969 2020-02-03
6970 2020-02-04
6971 2020-02-05
6972 2020-02-06
6973 2020-02-07
```

If you're getting your list of numbers from somewhere else, add/subtract appropriately from a start int/date for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create an object, which encapsulates the date and the base number to count from. Each call to this object (implemented using the `__call__` special method) will create a new date object using the time delta between the base number and the supplied number.

```py
import datetime


class RelativeDate:
    def __init__(self, date, base):
        self.date = date
        self.base = base

    def __call__(self, number):
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=number - self.base)
        return self.date + delta


def create_base_date(number, date):
    return RelativeDate(
        date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'),
        base=number,
    )


base_date = create_base_date(1, '03/01/2020')
base_date(3)
```

> datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 0, 0)

---

Example snippet:

```
base_date = create_base_date(1, '03/01/2020')
{i: base_date(i) for i in range(1, 10)}
```

Output:

```
{1: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 2: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 4, 0, 0),
 3: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 0, 0),
 4: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 0, 0),
 5: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 7, 0, 0),
 6: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 7: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 9, 0, 0),
 8: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 10, 0, 0),
 9: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 11, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try the above solutions you have provided